# how to Override FocusListener - Swing

Tags: java, swing

The application i work with override the default JComboBox from swing.  Leets Call it MyComboBox.  This version of ComboBox implement the FocusListener and contains the two methods focusGained and focusLost.

Now, in one of the panel of the application, the form contains a ComboBox of this type:

```
MyComboBox aMyComboBox = new MyComboBox();
```

I want to add a listener on this like that :

```
aMyComboBox.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
   public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
       //Do something here
   }
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
       //Do something else
   }
});
```

But when i run the code, it never pass into these method but only execute the focusGained/lost from the MyComboBox class.

Is there a way to add a listener on an object that already implements FocusListener?

Comment: Do you not have access to `MyComboBox`? Why add a new `FocusListener` if that class already implements it?

Comment: don't a) subclass any JSomething (they are meant to be used, not extended) b) expose api that is not meant for public usage, that is never "MyComponent implements SomeListener" c) use Focuslistener, it's far too low-level. If you insist, be aware that combo is a compound component which never itself will be the focus owner (see snoracle tutorial to learn how to recursively add the listener to the combo and all of its children)

Comment: Ok, MyComboBox have a general purpose FocusListener that do stuff i dont care about.  With my instance of MyComboBox inside my form, i want to execute some logic when the focusLost triggers.  So i would like to add a FocusListener on my instance of the object.  Don't know if its doable?

Comment: @Kleopatra My exerience with Swing is very low... but i agree with you on every points, but i didnt write this app... it was written in the 2000's and i have to do modifications inside it. :-(   If i can't use FocusListener, how can i listen to a selection change by the user on a comboBox then?

Comment: "my experience with Swing is low" - ever the more reason to read the tutorial :-)

Comment: @Kleo yes i read it, and ItemListener would be fine.... but the "BADS" who wrote this application decided to Implement ItemListeneer too in the MyComboBox class  .... Grrrrr   look like i'm screwed.

Comment: @Cygnusx1 and JComboBox has two states Editable and non-Editable, some methods are for Editable, some non-Editable, rest for both, please don't mix FocusListener with ItemListener, remove one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional FocusListener [should work](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) unless the instance used in MyComboBox consumes the event ([AWT event consumption](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html#consume%28%29)).

Try making an example with an ordinary JComboBox -- this will help narrowing down the cause of the problem.